# Create list of objects from Json object with objects in xamarin for Android

Tags: android, json, xamarin, json.net, deserialization

I`m using JSON.net and I'm trying to get a list of Expense objects from JSON like this:

```
{"ApplicationUser": null, "Currency": 1, "Description": "Moj pierwszy portfel", "Expenses": [{"Date": "2015-10-01T00:00:00", "Description": "Opis", "ExpenseType": {"Id": 1, "IsExpense": true, "Name": "Jedzenie"}, "ExpenseTypeId": 1, "Id": 1, "Name": "Biedronka", "Value": 40.00, "WalletId": 1}], "Id": 1, "Name": "Moj portfel", "Saldo": 100.12, "UserId": "f9b94a9a-44b3-4987-8711-6c1b73a5cb0e"}
```

api url: `http://homecalc.azurewebsites.net/api/wallets/2`

I have classes builded from [JSON2C#](http://json2csharp.com/#)

and they looks like this

```
public class ExpenseType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpense { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Expense
{
    public ExpenseType ExpenseType { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int ExpenseTypeId { get; set; }
    public int WalletId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public double Saldo { get; set; }
    public int Currency { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Getting JSONValue is declarated like this:

```
private async Task<JsonValue> GetApi(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                JsonValue jsconDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response {0}", stream);

                return jsconDoc;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried deserialization

```
var my_array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

and parsing it to jsonObject or jsonArray

```
var obj = JsonObject.Parse(json);
```

but it always ends with breaking the application.
I also try to get only array of expenses using `json["Expenses"]` but it returns all as one expense when there are two expenses. Could someone explain how to get a list of expense objects from this?

I've change code to look like this:

```
 private async Task<string> GetApi(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                JsonValue jsconDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response {0}", stream);
                StreamReader read = new StreamReader(stream,Encoding.UTF8);

                string json = read.ReadToEnd();

                return json;
            }
        }
    }

private void ParseAndDisplay(string json)
    {
        //TextView WalletName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PortfelName);
        //WalletName.Text = json["Name"];
        //Console.WriteLine("Exp {0}",json["Expenses"]);
        //JsonArray jsonnArray = new JsonArray(json["Expenses"]);
        try
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Nazwa: {0}",result.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Błąd: {0}",e);
        }

    }
```

and when i try to run this methods it return an exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: your API url throws an error when I call it.  And the sample json you posted only has a single expense in it.  Finally, what does "breaking the application" mean?  Do you get an exception?  What is it?

Comment: Also, your sample json is a single object, not an array, so deserializing to a List<RootObject> won't work.

Comment: It looks like the deserialization was close, but it is not clear how the input `json` was defined or populated. It should just be the string content of the response.

Comment: What line is the NullReferenceException triggered on? Chances are it is the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject call in ParseAndDisplay. If so, it could be because the stream in GetApi is already at end, because of the line above that loads JsonObject. I.e. when string json = read.ReadToEnd() is executed, json stays null.

Comment: Thanks Mark that was the problem, after all these changes code is running perfectly! Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting too far into details, using System.Net.Http.HttpClient and a JSON library like Newtonsoft.Json or ServiceStack.Text, this would be reasonably simple. Using Newtonsoft.Json, you might be looking for something like this:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    ...

    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    ...
}
```

Comment: I can't use response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync, 
response doeasn't seem to have Content method

Comment: My example is using System.Net.Http.HttpClient. I'll post a bit more of the code for that for completeness. I think you should be able to get your code using HttpWebRequest to work too, now that you are using the plain string loaded from the stream. You probably just need to comment out the two lines before `StreamReader read = ...`.