# System.NullReferenceException while passing data from Activity to FragmentActivity with Json using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I am getting the `System.NullReferenceException` error when I try to pass data from `Activity` to `FragmentActivity` using Json serialization and deserialization. Naturally it's possible to pass the kind of data I want (name, surname, company name etc.) simply with strings, but I want to use Json.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LoginList.Count; i++)
        {
            overload = i;
            Intent intent;
            if (LoginList[i].sUsername == login.Text && LoginList[i].sPassword == pass.Text)
            {
                int kind = LoginList[i].iAccountType;
                if (kind == 0)
                {
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ClientActivity));
                    intent.PutExtra("Client", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ClientList[0]));
                    StartActivity(intent);
                }`
}//there are two more kinds of accounts
```

`LoginList` is just a list of existing user logins (whole app is a demo), `ClientList` is a list of client accounts. `iAccountType` is an integer determining account type with 0 being client account type.

ClientActivity hosts a ViewPager with custom ActionBar consisting of several tabs (`Fragments`) with one of the tabs being MyAccount showing account info like name, surname etc.

**ClientActivity.cs**

```
public class ClientActivity : FragmentActivity, ActionBar.ITabListener 
{
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private ActionBar ClientBar;
    Client client;

    public class ClientFragmentAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public ClientFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) : base(fm)
        {
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return fragments.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ClientMain);

        //JSON DESERIALIZATION
        client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Client>(Intent.GetStringExtra("Client"));//this line causes the NullReference error

        // Create your application here
        fm = SupportFragmentManager;

        //VIEWPAGER
        viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
        viewPager.Adapter = new ClientFragmentAdapter(fm, GetFragments());
        viewPager.PageSelected += ViewPager_PageSelected;

        //ACTION BAR
        ClientBar = this.ActionBar;
        ClientBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        ClientBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        addTabs();

    }
```

I just wanna add that Xamarin has already thrown the exception mentioned in the title many times before for no reason. Up to this point, cleaning, rebuilding, deleting the error-causing part and rewriting it or even deleting the whole app and rewriting it worked for me, but I've already tried all of it to fix this error with no positive result.

Data tranfer part of the app is based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtLac9HpHSw

Comment: In your **ClientActivity** try to print the result of **Intent.GetStringExtra()**. If it is null, then you probably have problems in your **MainActivity**.

Comment: @TodorKostov printing the json string as a result of `GetStringExtra()` in `ClientActivity` works just fine

Comment: The other two possibilities I can think of are: invalid JSON format OR the **Client** object does not mach the JSON (typo or something else)

Comment: @TodorKostov can you please elaborate how JSON format can be invalid?

Comment: @TodorKostov OK, I found out there must be something wrong with `Client` class; I can pass `Login` objects with no errors. My previous question is invalid then, although a new one arises: how can `Client` object not match JSON?

Comment: Look at this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602909/create-list-of-objects-from-json-object-with-objects-in-xamarin-for-android
See how the names of the properties in  **RootObject** map precisely the keys from the given json from the above? That's what I am talking about. Check if the names of the properties in **Client** map precisely the keys from your json.